# Have a button start an option-select dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing for mobile and I have a select dropdown with different options, like so:

```
<select id="sorter" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled hidden>SORT</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select
```

Now, I want an uniform design. I have a filter button right beside it, that shows a new view with available filters. My idea is to have this sort select-dropdown have the same design as the filter button -- is this possible? As it's on mobile, it's really just a button that supposed to give the respective phone dropdown view.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could show us how the button / dropdown should look like.

Comment: can you share some mock-ups or wireframe

Comment: Well, basically, I already have css for my button, so I just want to be able to have a button that renders the dropdown on click. The design doesn't really have importance in this case!

Comment: Would it be an idea to use the bootstrap dropdown buttons? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help you. You can style any way you want.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  $(".selected").html($(this).find("span").html());
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
  <ul class="options">
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/00ff00"><span>Option 1</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/ff0000"><span>Option 2</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/0000ff"><span>Option 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```